# Keyboard Shortcuts during iChat Screen Sharing

Tags: keyboard, screen-sharing, ichat

## Switching Screens

I was just on an iChat-initiated Screen Sharing session with a friend, and had a really rough time telling him to get off the mouse so I can click back to my computer in order to look some stuff up.

Even when on my computer, as long as screen sharing is still active, the audio chat interface remains, so I can keep talking to him as I look up information he's asking for.

Doing this, while watching his screen, was an aggrivating task. How does one switch back to their computer without asking for mouse access to do so?

## Ending the Sharing Session

Are there alternate keyboard shortcuts for ending a screen sharing session? The menu bar lists <kbd>^ ⎋</kbd> for achieving this (⎋ is the power button on your computer). However, I'm stuck in a really annoying middle ground.

At work, I have a MacBook Pro, plugged into a Cinema display, external keyboard (mini-style/no-numpad style), and magic mouse, and I use my laptop with the lid closed. Thus, I have no power button.

Can I end the session without asking for mouse access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there alternate keyboard shortcuts for ending a screen sharing session? The menu bar lists <kbd>^ ⎋</kbd> for achieving this (⎋ is the power button on your computer). However, I'm stuck in a really annoying middle ground.

Actually, the symbol that you're referring to references the "Esc" key.

So, by pressing <kbd>^ ⎋</kbd> (Control-Esc) you can end the Screen Sharing session without asking for control of the mouse.

Comment: *boggles* Umm, wow. That's true, because Alt Command Esc brings up Force Quit. I must test this for real to ensure that's the case.

Comment: Now that I've verified that you are entirely correct, gladly! That's really crazy, and really good to know. Thank you. (Sorry, I don't screen share very often.)